# Unstable result xgboost model tunning with baysian optimisation Python

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, xgboost

I have a problem with my xgboost model tuned with bayesian optimization. Each time I run the model with the same input data, I get different results. The optimal settings change each time I run the model again.

Can you tell me how to solve this problem of unstable results?

Thank you

Here is the script :

```
def mean_absolute_percentage_error(y_true,y_pred): 
    """Calculates MAPE given y_true and y_pred"""
    dat_ = pd.DataFrame()
    dat_["y_true"]=list(y_true)
    dat_["y_pred"] =y_pred
    dat_=dat_[dat_["y_true"]!=0]
    y_true, y_pred = np.array(dat_["y_true"]), np.array(dat_["y_pred"])
    return np.mean(np.abs((y_true - y_pred) / y_true)) * 100

def xgb_evaluate(max_depth, gamma, colsample_bytree,subsample,eta):
    params = {'eval_metric': "rmse",
          'max_depth': int(max_depth),
          'subsample': subsample,
          'eta':eta,
          'gamma': gamma,
          'colsample_bytree': colsample_bytree}
    # Used around 1000 boosting rounds in the full model
    #cv_result = xgb.cv(params, dtrain, num_boost_round=100, nfold=3)    

    model = XGBRegressor( **params)
    model2 = model.fit(X_train, y_train, eval_set=[(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test)],
          verbose=False, early_stopping_rounds=20)

    # Bayesian optimization only knows how to maximize, not minimize, so return the negative RMSE
    return -(1.0 * mean_absolute_percentage_error(y_test,model2.predict(X_test)))


X_train = pd.DataFrame(data_train.drop(['Pieces'], axis=1))
y_train = data_train['Pieces']

X_test = pd.DataFrame(data_test.drop(['Pieces'], axis=1))
y_test = data_test['Pieces']
    
xgb_bo =None
xgb_bo = BayesianOptimization(xgb_evaluate, {'max_depth': (3, 200), 
                                         'gamma': (0, 1),
                                         'colsample_bytree': (0.3, 0.9),
                                         "subsample":(0.5,0.9),
                                         "eta": (0.1,0.5)})
# Use the expected improvement acquisition function to handle negative numbers
# Optimally needs quite a few more initiation points and number of iterations
xgb_bo.maximize(init_points=3, n_iter=100, acq='ei')
    
params = xgb_bo.max['params']
params['max_depth'] = int(params['max_depth'])

#model2 = xgb.train(params, dtrain, num_boost_round=250)
model_impl = XGBRegressor(**params)
model_Fitted = model_impl.fit(X_train, y_train, eval_set=[(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test)],
        verbose=False, early_stopping_rounds=10)
```

Comment: Maybe it is a problem related to the structure of the input data? Can you let us see the data?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you M. Khaled for your reply.
The input data has the following structure:

[image]